# Why do I get an error when I try to make items in a record integers?

Tags: python, list, math, python-3.x, record

I have a little problem with my code here. The aim of this code is to get the users' score to be paired with their name in a tuple and then sort these scores alphabetically, numerically and eventually be averaged. I'm on the verge of completing this project but this error continues to hold me back so I'm hoping to gain assistance from the programming community.

```
if Class == 'Year5S':
    Year5S = open ('Year5S.txt', 'r')
    Year5S = Year5S.read()
    print ('\nThe others in your class have scored the following:\n' + Year5S + '\n')

    Year5Sa = open ('Year5S.txt', 'a')
    Year5Sa.write (Name)
    Year5Sa.write (",")
    Year5Sa.write (str(Score))
    Year5Sa.write (",")
    Year5Sa.close()
    print("Would you like to see the scores sorted Alphabetically, Numerically or Averaged?")
    order=input()

i=0
record={}

itemsS = Year5S.split(",")
length = len(itemsS)
length = length-1
average_dict={}
average = {}



for i in range(0,length,2): #We are incrementing by 2 because we want to jump to every other item in the list (names of teams)
        Firstname = itemsS[i]
        score = itemsS[i+1]
        record[Firstname]=score
        if Firstname not in average_dict:
            average_dict[Firstname] = []
            average_dict[Firstname].append(score)
        if len(average_dict[Firstname]) >3:
            average_dict[Firstname].pop(0)
        if Firstname not in average:
            collection = sum(average_dict[Firstname])/len(average_dict[Firstname])
            collection = round(collection)
            average[Firstname] = collection

sorted_average = sorted(average.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse = True)



sorted_Alist=sorted(record.items(), key=lambda x: x[0])



sorted_Nlist=sorted(record.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])



if order == "Alphabetically":
        print(sorted_Alist)

elif order == "Numerically":
        print(sorted_Nlist)

elif order == "Averaged":
        print(sorted_average)
```

I continue to get this error.

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Downloads\Arithmetic Game Experimental.py", line 125, in <module>
    collection = sum(average_dict[Firstname])/len(average_dict[Firstname])
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

I attempted to make the record an integer but it was a failed attempt and I was given this error. `typeerror: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'`

How can I make the record an integer so that I can add the scores within the integer and divide them by the number of scores inside to get an average? Thanks in advance.

These are the contents of the text file.
`Olachi Akin, 5, Olachi Akin, 5, Olachi Akin 7,Olachi Akin,1,Olachi Akin,1,Olachi Akin,0,Olachi Akin,0,Olachi Akin,0,Olachi Akin,0,Olachi Akin,0,Olachi Akin,1,Olachi Akin,2,Olachi Akin,0,Olachi Akin,0,Olachi Akin,0,Olachi Akin,1,Olachi Akin,0,Olachi Akin,0,Olachi Akin,0,Olachi Akin,1,Olachi Akin,0,Olachi Akin,0,Olachi Akin,0,Olachi Akin,0,`

Comment: Please edit your question down to an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and paste the actual traceback when you try to cast something as a `list`.

Comment: I've edited the question but isn't the traceback I put there sufficient? Sorry I don't use stack much so I'm still quite new to it. @TigerhawkT3

Comment: @iExodus you put too much code. Follow the link from TigerhawkT3 , it gives advice on how to build a _minimal_ example.

Comment: There's a traceback with `TypeError` and the line number and the line content, which is good, but then you mention an error with `typeerror` instead of `TypeError` and no information such as line numbers. Also, please `print` the value of `average_dict[Firstname]` before executing the line that generates an error and let us know what it contains. Judging by your comment on @Eric's answer, it contains a `list` with a single string. You can't `sum()` those (even with a `""` argument).

Comment: I did what you said and printed the value of `average_dict[Firstname]` which came up with `[' 5']` @TigerhawkT3

Comment: That is a string consisting of a space followed by a numeric character. `int([' 5'][0].strip())` will produce the integer `5`.

Comment: So something like `int(average_dict[Firstname][0].strip())` would work? @TigerhawkT3

Comment: I don't have your test data. Make the change, test it, and see if it works.

Comment: The problem is here:  
Olachi Akin 7 The comma is missing...

Comment: Ok so I did this. `average_dict[Firstname] = int(average_dict[Firstname][0].strip())` so it is now in integer form, however, this error came up afterwards. `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Downloads\Arithmetic Game Experimental.py", line 126, in <module>
    collection = sum(average_dict[Firstname])/len(average_dict[Firstname])
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

Comment: If you now have an integer, you cannot send it to `len()`, because integers don't have length. You need to take a closer look at what data structures you're using, how you build them, and what you expect to do with them.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
score = itemsS[i+1]
```

by

```
score = int(itemsS[i+1])
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\user\Downloads\Arithmetic Game Experimental.py", line 117, in <module> score = int(itemsS[i+1]) ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Olachi Akin'

Comment: Ok it's there now, but I'm not sure it's the problem as I'm simply trying to split the file.

Comment: The problem is in the file. Can you add the content of the file, especially the items juste before Olachi Akin?

Comment: ok changes have been made to show file contents. @Eric Levieil